# Laravel app on xampp subfolder without navigating to public folder

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, xampp, laravel-7

I have a laravel app on `C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name` which means I have to navigate to `http://localhost/project_name/public/`. What I want is to just visit `http://localhost/project_name/`.

I tried adding the following .htaccess on `C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But that doesn't work. I know I can use `php artisan serve` or even rename `server.php` to `index.php` and copy the `.htaccess` from `/public` but I am trying to find a better solution.

Comment: you could create a `vhost` and put `DocumentRoot` to `C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/public`: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: @swadhwa I tried `vhost` and chrome says: `Your connection is not private` when I navigate to the servername I created.

Comment: you also need to add an entry of your `servername` in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. this file gets looked up during dns resolution before approaching the local dns server. enter this: `servername  127.0.0.1`

Comment: @swadhwa Yes, I know. It turns out it doesn't work if the servername ends with `.dev`. I changed to `projectname.local` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit the DocumentRoot in your httpd.conf file.

http://blog.mdsohelrana.com/2011/11/01/how-to-change-the-document-root-in-xampp-on-windows/

Comment: You can also go about by setting up virtual hosts https://ultimatefosters.com/hosting/setup-a-virtual-host-in-windows-with-xampp-server/

If you want a better environment I would suggest you to switch to Laragon for a better experience. I am using it from last 2 months.  https://laragon.org/